# fcm-django push notifications to mobile app messages is falling

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new with Firebase. The problem is that the sending of messages is falling. I suspect this is due to lack of Firebase authentication.

So, what I did:

1. I created new Firebase project and turn on an Anonymous authentication on project settings.
2. On the backend side I installed fcm-django, add settings, and make migrations. Settings:

```
# Firebase app
certificate = json.loads(config('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS', default=''))
cred = credentials.Certificate(certificate)
FIREBASE_APP = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

FCM_DJANGO_SETTINGS = {
    "DEFAULT_FIREBASE_APP": FIREBASE_APP,
    "APP_VERBOSE_NAME": ("FCM Brokers CRM notifications"),
    "ONE_DEVICE_PER_USER": False,
    "DELETE_INACTIVE_DEVICES": False,
}
```

3. Add standard route from this library:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('devices', FCMDeviceAuthorizedViewSet)
path('', include(router.urls)),
```

4. I call **post device/** endpoint with my drf auth user, and send only registration_id (firebase token). Is it enough? So I see in database id of user
   from AUTH_USER_MODEL: [image]
5. I have simple test endpoint with code:

```
from firebase_admin.messaging import Message, Notification
...
devices = FCMDevice.objects.filter(user=request.user)
from device in devices:
    device.send_message(Message(
        notification=Notification(title="title", body="text"),
        topic="Optional topic parameter: Whatever you want",
    ))
```

And I call it from my android app. But its fall with error:
[image]

I really desperate and don't know what to do. Do I have to somehow add another user and connect it to the endpoint call? Or I have to match the android app with my firebase? Any advices how can I fix it? Thanks a lot!